# Image in UIImageView Stretches

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I have seen different posts on stackoverflow for the same issue but none of them worked for me hence I am posting my query

I am working on a application where I am picking images from the image gallery and placing it on my `UIImageView` instance

```
drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"]];
[drawImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
drawImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
drawImage.clipsToBounds = YES;

[drawImage setFrame:self.view.frame];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(drawImage.frame.size));
[self.view addSubview:drawImage];
```

This is the code for the image gallery

```
imagePickerObj.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
imagePickerObj.allowsEditing=YES;
```

When i pick the image from the gallery i am using the below code

```
UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
NSLog(@" B4 crop Image size %@",NSStringFromCGSize(img.size));
NSLog(@" B4 crop DrawImage size %@",NSStringFromCGSize(drawImage.frame.size));

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,drawImage.frame.size.width,drawImage.frame.size.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

NSLog(@"After crop Image size %@",NSStringFromCGSize(newImage.size));
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


// drawImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
drawImage.image = newImage;
```

The issue is that no matter what image i pick it always appears to be a little stretched from the above code that i have added for the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` it decreases the width and height of the image but it still appears stretched.

I have even tried changing the content mode of the image view to `AspectFill` and `AspectFit` but alas no luck at all.

Could you guide me out on where I am making mistake?

Comment: @Divya : I tried changing the content mode to center but it chops off my image, to be more specific my DrawImage is of the size 320 x 460 and the images that i pic from the gallery are slightly of the higher size somewhat about 640 x 960. Even with the current code base i am able to make the size of the image from the gallery  to 320 x 480 but still it stretches.

Comment: Hmm, Not doing any good could you specify me the method i have used the UIImage+Resize category is there anything that i am missing